# Making a regex with a lookbehind

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that replaces the usual hyphen with the non-break hyphen, if it’s found inside of a *word*

```
preg_replace('@(?<= \w)-(?= \w)@xu','‑',$string);
```

But there are strings like `"this is a link":http://example.com/funny-stuff-is-funny`, which are get parsed too. The problem is further parsing such string breaks because of the non-break hyphen inside of the link. So I need or to modify the original regex to not match links, or to cover the whole function in another where I will fix that behavior. The first way I tried to go ended at this

```
'@((?<! http)[/\pL\pP]+\w)-(?= \w)@xu'
```

It matches `link":http://example.com/funny-` and still replaces the hyphen. So I went the second way and get the following thing:

```
preg_replace( /* Fixing broken links with NON-BREAKING HYPHEN */
             '@(https?\://[^\s]+)‑@',
             '$1===-===', /* This is to make a better view */
             preg_replace( /* NON-BREAKING HYPHEN inside of a word */
                          '@(?<= \w)-(?= \w)@xu',
                          '‑',
                          $string))));
```

And with this we can have replaced hyphen in links. A single one hyphen:

```
"this is a link":http://example.com/funny-things-are===-===funny
```

I’ve tried to change ‘greediness’ of the covering expression with `‘U’` but it doesn’t seem to fix it, so I’m asking for help.

**===upd===**

I accepted solution with `preg_replace_callback()` as a general idea, but I had to use `preg_replace()` inside of it because of multibyte encoding.

Comment: what about bad urls that have unencoded spaces in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general approach is to use a custom callback. Try the following, if you want to take the fix-broken-links way:

```
    $string = '"a dumb-ass car":http://example.com/funny-stuff-is-funny - funny-enough?';

    echo preg_replace_callback( /* Fixing broken links with NON-BREAKING HYPHEN */
                 '@https?\://[^\s]+‑[^\s]+@u',
                 function ($matches) {
                         return str_replace('‑', '$1===-===', $matches[0]);
                         // or better, use strtr() for one-character replacement:
                         // return strtr($matches[0], '‑', '-');
                 },
                 preg_replace( /* NON-BREAKING HYPHEN inside of a word */
                              '@(?<= \w)-(?= \w)@xu',
                              '‑',
                              $string));
```